# Workflow 4, Why WaitForInput can not accept Input=[command]

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I'm trying to implement a multi steps wizard using WF4 for my MVC project. I've installed "Client Profile Platform Update 1" on my machine and I've implemented my project based on this sample : 
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Multiple-Step-Based-Registration-via-ASP-NET-MVC-2-WF-4.aspx#1797

The problem is when I add a "WaitForInput" to first step of my 'Activity' , and I try to set Input=[command] , the expression validation shows me this error : 
 
**Compiler error(s) encountered processing expression "command". Invalid L-value expression.** 
Please note that I have to pass the "command" as input to "RunWorkFlow" method (in order to detecting the next step), and if I leave Input as null, instanceUnloaded.WaitOne() does not receive any signal from System.Threading to dispose the current step and instantiate the next Step. 
Apparently, "command" was a variable in WF3.5 , but WF4 does not accept it.
Any idea?